# Wrong cursor position of Ace Editor inside a dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css, dialog, ace-editor

According to Ace Editor embedding guidelines [Ace Embedding](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding) I added Ace to my website.

You can also view here the simplest working example of Ace Editor in a working example(not mine) [Ace Editor jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/sd4ma/)

But I face the following problem:

I want to add the div of editor inside a dialog but I face a problem with editor's cursor position inside my dialog when typing.

**Cursor is always displayed more right than where it should be.**

[image: Check here the wrong cursor position]

Is there any idea how it might be fixed?

Keep in mind that cursor position of Ace editor in my website works great before adding it inside a dialog.

Here is the exact code of my editor and my dialog:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="dialog-message" title="Script Editor">
        <div id="editor" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>  

    <!--  Ace Dependencies: -->
    <script src="./ace/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    </script>
```

**CSS**

```
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #editor { 
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }           

    </style>
```

**Javascript**

```
                $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                width: 800,
                height:600,
                buttons: {
                    "Download Workitem Code": function() {
                        /*Create the content of file workitem.html*/
                        var currentEditorValue = editor.getValue();

                        /*HTTP request to get the code of sample_workitem.html*/
                        var url = 'http://patrasrv.motivian.com:8080/BPM_PRODUCT/docroot/designer_standalone/bpm_designer/sample_workitem.html';

                        $(function() {
                          $.get(url, function(data) {

                            var htmlCode = data.replace("[[[[[AAAAA]]]]]", editor.getValue());

                            /*Download workitem.html*/
                            var filename = 'workitem.html';
                            var contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
                            var a = document.createElement('a');
                            var blob = new Blob([htmlCode], {
                              'type': contentType
                            });
                            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            a.download = filename;
                            a.click();          

                          });
                        });


                    },
                    "Save Script": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        cell.set('wi_script_on_page', $("#editor").text());
                        cell.set('wi_script_editor', false);
                        var testing = editor.getValue();
                        cell.set('wi_script_on_page', testing);
                    },
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                open: function(){
                    $('#editor').show();
                    $('#editor').focus();
                },
                close: function() {
                        //When closing form by pressing 'X'
                        $('#editor').hide();
                        cell.set('wi_script_editor', false);
                }
            });
```

Ignore the functionality of 3 dialog buttons. It has nothing to do with the problem itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have some css rule that changes font family of ace when you put it into dialog.
You need to make sure that the font family set to ace is monospace.

Comment: I set editor.setOptions({fontFamily: "monospace"}); both during initialization script of editor and inside function open of dialog but the problem still remains. I cannot figure out a solution to this really irritating problem.

Comment: you have a css rule that overrides style set by ace. use browser devtools to find the rule, or create a page demonstrating the problem and i can find it for you

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with the procedure. What should I look at my developer tools ? Can you send me a screenshot to understand or some guidelines to understand what I have to do?

Comment: I forgot to tell you that you are definitely right as for the css rule in my project which creates the problem. I updated a jsfiddle which I found on the Internet  which now contains a dialog and cursor workes like a charm. http://jsfiddle.net/zmdf50q1/ So how can I find my own css issue?

Comment: This might help you. It is my editor CSS from my Developer Tools . https://prnt.sc/hw04qi

Comment: just look for font-family rules in the styles panel, `.ui-widget *` rule in your screenshot is definitely interfering with ace, since it is changing style of all nodes in ace, but there may be other rules too

Comment: It worked like a charm. The only problem was the use of CSS rule .ui-widget * in my local environment. Thank you so much. A very irritating bug was fixed and now it works flawlessly.